# What kind of hyper-surfaces are those defined by equation $(x\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x})=\rho\geqslant0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

What kind of hyper-surfaces, functions I am dealing with here?

A smooth hyper-surface $S^{n-1}$ in $R^{n}$ is defined by an equation $(x\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x})=\rho>0$ with a smooth positive definite (non-homogeneous) function $f(x)>0$  for  $\forall x\in R^{n}\setminus0$ and an assumption that a regular (finite) solution of the above equation exist for all radial directions of $x$.

1. Looks like that it is homeomorphic to a (n-1)-sphere in $R^{n}$ with $0$ as its volume internal point. It seems to be kind of convex, but not in terms of any strict notion of convexity I am aware of. What are those types of surfaces in general? Or these types of functions?
2. Let us now include the possibility of (limit to) $\rho=0$.
   How to make sure that the function $f(x)$ is such, that equation $(x\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x})=0$ has the only solution $x=0$? 
   Will positive Hessian suffice? Positive semi-definite in a vicinity of $0$ only?  Will it be necessary, or sufficient, or both? Are there any theorems on this?

I'll be really grateful for a help in clarifying the concepts and for useful specific references.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a "positive definite function"? ... Note that by Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions, the level sets of any *homogeneous* function will fit this description.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It probably pays to add that in this case function $f(x)$ is not meant  to be any homogeneous. But, it seems in some sense even not being actually homogeneous it might be somewhat similar.

Comment: BTW, even for a homogeneous function the second part: $(x∂f(x)∂x)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=0$ in general is not guaranteed.